# AWS : How to guarantee availability of static Private IP while bootstrapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, amazon-emr

I am launching EMR cluster and while bootstrapping I am assigning a Private IP address to it master node. So this get associated when cluster starts and gets released when cluster gets terminated. 
How do i guarantee that this IP is always available for my cluster and no other process picks it up even when not in use.

Once I get this Ip, I submit my spark jars to 8998 port of this IP, using Apache livy REST API

So my use case is to expose the IP on master node, so that LIVY APIs can submit job to EMR.

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your use-case? For example, why do you want a static private IP address? There might be another way to achieve your objective (eg using DNS names), but you'll need to tell us more. Please edit your question to add details rather than adding a comment.

Comment: You can create a `network interface` and attach it to master node. But you need to configure other services (like yarn, hadoop, etc.) to work with the 2ndary network interface. Once the cluster is terminated your interface will automatically gets detached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to request a specific private IP address for the cluster.

Instead, I would suggest:

- Create a Route 53 private hosted zone with a Record Set for the cluster (eg `cluster.private`)
- After launching the EMR cluster, update the Record Set for the IP address of the master node
- Have Apache Livy reference the cluster by DNS Name rather than IP address

Updating the Record Set can be done programmatically. A script would do something like:

- Call `list_clusters()`
- For each cluster, call `describe_cluster()`
- Look for a tag (eg `DNS=cluster.private`)
- If the `DNS` tag is present:

  - Update the named Record Set in Route 53 to use an A-Record to point to the IP address of the master node

This script would need to be triggered after the cluster is launched.

Comment: Thanks much. I will try this out and post here.